# Setting Backbon.Marionette using RequireJS with CDN

Tags: requirejs, marionette

I'm trying to set a Backbone project with Marionette extension using requireJS.
I couldn't make it work when using one of the CDNs like cdnjs.
Does anyone know of a good example mixing these three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an example of using Backbone.Marionette with Require, you can find it here :
http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/bPMwEqPz1sYod46Stfhk

You just need to click run to confirm that Mariontte is working from a CDN.

in this example you have the html open by default, but in the menu you will find the script.js that im using to load everything with require.

hope this heps.